# How to merge .stl files properly in Blender

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing, stl

I want to merge the .stl files properly in Blender. I am new to Blender, don't judge me. I was trying to combine them manually but I could not. Is there any way to do this like some automatic features in Blender?

[image: Here are my stl files]

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "merge"? Make all separate objects just one object where they are now? Or rotate and place them so that they fit together in the supposed places automatically? Or not just place them correctly but also merge the pieces so that they form a fully connected mesh?

Comment: As you can see it is a Gollum. I want to connect the parts properly and take just one .stl file.

Comment: There's no automatic button that will do this automagiclly you have to manually tell blender where you want to place the parts and merge them.  I think you may want to use the `Boolean modifier`   https://all3dp.com/2/blender-how-to-merge-objects/

Comment: I would be grateful if you mention how to manually tell the blender to place the parts. Do you mean just grabbing and putting? I was not successful at it.